# How to fix this prisma query problem in nestjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, nestjs, prisma

I have the following query which is running fine on express with knex. But when I try to convert it into prisma in NestJs it throwing me error.

`
async fetchCompanyActivities(
body: GetCompanyDetailDto,
member_id: number,
facility_id: number,
) {
const {
latitude,
longitude,
start_date,
end_date,
keyword,
activity_type_ids,
zone_ids,
} = body;
// const numberOfDaysToAdd = process.env.company_activity_no_of_days;
const numberOfDaysToAdd = 15;

```
const unit = 6371;
const currentDate = new Date();
const curTime =
  currentDate.getHours() +
  ':' +
  currentDate.getMinutes() +
  ':' +
  currentDate.getSeconds();

const memberQuery1 = member_id ? ` AND m0_.member_id = '${member_id}'` : '';
const memberQuery2 = member_id
  ? ` LEFT JOIN
                        (SELECT
                          schedule_detail_id ,IF(member_id = '${member_id}' , 1,0) self_booked
                          FROM
                          member_schedule_activity
                          WHERE
                          status IN ('${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_BOOKED}','${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_RESERVED}')
                          OR (STATUS = '${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_EXPIRED}' AND checkin = 1)
                          GROUP BY schedule_detail_id,member_id) m4_ ON m4_.schedule_detail_id = s3_.id `
  : '';
const memberQuery3 = member_id ? ` OR IFNULL(m4_.self_booked,1)=1` : '';
const memberQuery4 = member_id ? ` AND member_id = '${member_id}'` : '';

const distanceQuery =
  latitude && longitude
    ? `,(
      ${unit} *
      acos(cos(radians(${latitude})) *
      cos(radians(IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.latitude, a2_.latitude))) *
      cos(radians(IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.longitude, a2_.longitude)) -
          radians(${longitude})) +
          sin(radians(${latitude})) *
      sin(radians(IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.latitude, a2_.latitude))))
      ) AS distance`
    : '';

const distanceOrderByQuery =
  latitude && longitude ? `ORDER BY distance DESC` : '';

const dateFilterQuery =
  start_date && end_date
    ? `AND s3_.schedule_date >= '${start_date} ${curTime}' AND s3_.schedule_date <= '${end_date}'`
    : `AND DATE_ADD(s3_.schedule_date, INTERVAL s3_.duration MINUTE ) > 
  (SELECT _sd.schedule_date FROM schedule_detail _sd
  INNER JOIN activity_schedule _as ON _as.id=_sd.schedule_id
  WHERE _as.facility_id = '${facility_id}' AND _sd.schedule_date >= NOW() ORDER BY _sd.schedule_date ASC LIMIT 1) 
  AND s3_.schedule_date <= DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT((SELECT _sd.schedule_date FROM schedule_detail _sd
  INNER JOIN activity_schedule _as ON _as.id=_sd.schedule_id
  WHERE _as.facility_id = '${facility_id}' AND _sd.schedule_date >= NOW() ORDER BY _sd.schedule_date ASC LIMIT 1),'%Y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL ${numberOfDaysToAdd} DAY)`;

const keywordFilterQuery = keyword
  ? `AND (f1_.company_name LIKE '%${keyword}%' OR f1_.address LIKE '%${keyword}%' OR a2_.pinaddress LIKE '%${keyword}%' OR at_.name LIKE '%${keyword}%')`
  : '';

const activityTypeFilterQuery =
  activity_type_ids && activity_type_ids.length
    ? `AND at_.id IN (${activity_type_ids.join(',')})`
    : '';

const zoneFilterQuery =
  zone_ids && zone_ids.length
    ? `AND a2_.facilityZone_id IN (${zone_ids.join(',')})`
    : '';

const query = `SELECT DISTINCT
                              s3_.id AS schedule_detail_id,
                              fz.title zone,
                              IFNULL(m3_.booked_slots,0) booked_slots,
                              s3_.slots AS slots,
                              s3_.schedule_id AS classId,
                              a4_.id AS activityId,
                              a4_.NAME AS name,
                              at_.NAME AS actt_name,
                              a4_.CODE AS code,
                              a4_.description AS description,
                              a4_.imageName AS activityImage,
                              at_.imageName AS activityTypeImage,
                              a2_.is_free AS isFree,
                              a2_.offer_online AS offer_online,
                              a2_.allow_corepass AS isCorePass,
                              a2_.recurrence AS recurrence,
                              s3_.duration AS duration,
                              DATE_FORMAT(s3_.schedule_date,'%h:%i %p') AS startTime,
                              DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(s3_.schedule_date, INTERVAL s3_.duration MINUTE ), '%h:%i %p') endTime,
                              DATE_ADD(s3_.schedule_date, INTERVAL s3_.duration MINUTE ) class_end_date_time,
                              instrutor_.title AS instructor_name,
                              a2_.duration AS slot_duration,
                              a2_.facility_id AS facilityId,
                              f1_.company_name AS facility,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.latitude, a2_.latitude)  AS classLatitude,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.longitude, a2_.longitude)  AS classLongitude,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.latitude, a2_.latitude)  AS facilityLatitude,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.longitude, a2_.longitude)  AS facilityLongitude,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 1 AND  LENGTH (a2_.pinaddress ) > 0 , a2_.pinaddress, f1_.address)  AS address,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 1 AND  LENGTH (a2_.pinaddress ) > 0 , a2_.pinaddress, f1_.address)  AS activity_schedule_address,
                              f1_.company_logo AS facilityImage,
                              a2_.startDate AS a_startDate,
                              DATE_FORMAT(s3_.schedule_date,'%a,%M %D %Y') AS startDate,
                              a2_.endDate AS endDate,
                              a2_.updated_date AS lastUpdated,
                              s3_.schedule_date AS classDate,
                              m0_.is_favourite AS is_favourite_0,
                              m0_.checkin AS checkin_1,
                              m0_.STATUS AS status,
                              m0_.id AS msa_id,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.latitude, a2_.latitude)  AS latitude,
                              IF( a2_.is_location = 0 , f1_.longitude, a2_.longitude)  AS longitude,
                              a2_.id AS id_5,
                              a2_.is_recommended AS is_recommended ${distanceQuery}
                            FROM
                              activity_schedule a2_
                            INNER JOIN schedule_detail s3_ ON a2_.id = s3_.schedule_id
                            INNER JOIN activity a4_ ON a2_.activity_id = a4_.id
                            INNER JOIN facility_zones fz ON fz.id = a2_.facilityZone_id
                            INNER JOIN activity_type at_ ON a4_.activity_type_id = at_.id 
                            INNER JOIN activity_schedule_package a6_ ON
                                a2_.id = a6_.activityschedule_id
                            INNER JOIN package p5_ ON
                                p5_.id = a6_.package_id
                            LEFT JOIN instructor instrutor_ ON
                                        s3_.instructor_id = instrutor_.id AND(instrutor_.is_deleted = 0)
                            INNER JOIN fos_user_user f1_ ON a2_.facility_id = f1_.id
                            LEFT JOIN member_schedule_activity m0_ ON m0_.schedule_detail_id = s3_.id AND m0_.STATUS != '${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_CANCELLED}' ${memberQuery1}
                            LEFT JOIN (
                            SELECT
                                COUNT(id) booked_slots, schedule_detail_id
                            FROM
                                member_schedule_activity 
                            WHERE
                              STATUS IN ('${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_BOOKED}','${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_RESERVED}')
                              OR (STATUS = '${CompanyInfoType.STATUS_EXPIRED}' AND checkin = 1)
                              group by schedule_detail_id
                            ) m3_ ON m3_.schedule_detail_id = s3_.id 
                            
                            ${memberQuery2}
                                
                        WHERE
                            a2_.is_deleted = 0 
                            ${dateFilterQuery}  
                            ${keywordFilterQuery}
                            ${activityTypeFilterQuery}
                            ${zoneFilterQuery}
                          AND ( f1_.enabled = 1 )
                            AND a2_.facility_id IN (${facility_id})
                            AND s3_.is_deleted = 0 
                            AND s3_.is_cancel = 0 
                             AND (a2_.is_free = 1 OR (p5_.is_deleted = 0 AND ( p5_.expires_on > curdate() OR p5_.repeat_monthly = 1 ) ))
                        GROUP BY s3_.id 
                                ORDER BY
                             s3_.schedule_date
                             LIMIT 100`;

const activities = await this.prismaService.$queryRaw(Prisma.sql`${query}`);
return activities;
```

}
`

Error:
`err: { "type": "PrismaClientKnownRequestError", "message": "\nInvalid`prisma.$queryRaw()`invocation:\n\n\nRaw query failed. Code:`1064`. Message:` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?\n                                FROM\n                                  activit' at line 45`", "stack": Error:  Invalid` prisma.$queryRaw()` invocation:

```
      Raw query failed. Code: `1064`. Message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?
                                      FROM
                                        activit' at line 45`
   at Pn.handleRequestError (.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:6929)
   at Pn.handleAndLogRequestError(.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:6358)
   at Pn.request (.../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:171:6237)
          at UserRepository.fetchCompanyActivities (.../dist/apps/user/main.js:9706:28)
          at UserService.getCompanyDetail (.../dist/apps/user/main.js:10521:19)
  "code": "P2010",
  "clientVersion": "4.14.1",
  "meta": {
    "type": "Object",
    "message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?\n                                FROM\n                                  activit' at line 45",
    "stack":
        
    "code": "1064"
  }
```

`

I expact it returns me activites detail which I already get from expressJs app.